# How to fetch the data of an array of business ids using Yelp API?

Tags: javascript, axios, yelp

I have an long array containing ids of businesses and I want to fetch each business data associated with the id.

Although using axios and the right headers gives me the result, I still get some of the data missing due to the following error/exception: `TOO_Many_Requests_Per_Second`.

The code I use for fetching the data is as follows:

```
const headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer <token>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      };
 data.maps(async (product : any) => {
        const res = await axios.get(`${URLS.FETCH_BUSINESS_DETAILS}/${product.businessId}`, { headers      });
      });
```

Comment: `TOO_Many_Requests_Per_Second` means that your requests are getting throttled by Yelp.  Have you checked their docs to see what is allowed and not allowed for number of request per second? https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/qps_rate_limiting

Comment: Yeah, I used a sleep functions with 200ms gap, I guess I need to increase this slot a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The developer docs for the Yelp API has the following information about this error response:

#### Queries-Per-Second (QPS) Rate Limiting

**QPS Limit**

If you make queries against the API too quickly, you may get HTTP 429 errors with the json body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND",
        "description": "You have exceeded the queries-per-second limit for this endpoint.
                        Try reducing the rate at which you make queries."
    }
}
```

**If you are seeing these regularly, please slow down the rate at which you are making calls to the API.**